# Giving the same variable multiple values

Tags: python

I want to give "a" variable different numbers and let the user guess a number, if the number guessed is similar to **one** of the numbers then print out "correct"

```
a = 1, 
5, 
10

b = input("Guess one of the numbers: ")

if b == a:
    print("Correct")

else:
    print ("Wrong")
```

Comment: `a = [1,5,10]` and `if b in a`

Comment: A variable can only hold one value at a time. That value may be a *container* though, like a `list`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment to `a` succeeds, but *ends* with the newline. `a` is a singleton tuple. `a = 1, 5, 10` on *one* line is the 3-element tuple you want; spread across multiple lines, you need parentheses

```
a = (1,
5,
10
)
```

or explicit line continuations

```
a = 1, \
5, \
10
```

Once you have the correct tuple, you need to use *containment*, not equality, to see if `b` is one of the numbers. You also need to convert the string input to an integer first.

```
b = int(input("Guess one of the numbers: "))

if b in a:
    print("Correct")

else:
    print ("Wrong")
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you so much!